# Is there a pre-compiler define that tells me I'm compiling for iOS?

Tags: configuration, c-preprocessor

Is there a pre-compiler define that tells me I'm compiling for iOS?

Something like `__APPLE__` that lets me know I'm compiling on a mac.

Comment: What compiler, and what language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure; in GCC:

```c
#ifdef __APPLE__
  #include "TargetConditionals.h"

  #ifdef TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    // targeting the iPhone
  #elif TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    // targeting the iOS simulator
  #elif TARGET_OS_MAC
    // targeting the Mac OS
  #else
    // unknown target platform
  #endif
#else
  // non-Apple platform
#endif
```